# Full width boxed equation

Tags: amsmath, tcolorbox, empheq

I would like to use `empheq` to box center aligned equations but would like the boxes to span the full page width.

1. Passing the `gather/gather*` environment to `empheq` produces the center aligned equations but the box is tight around the contents of the equations.
2. Passing the `flalign/flalign*` environment to `empheq` produces the full width box but aligning equations to the center is a bit of a hassle -- must be done manually and requires a bit of guesswork to get the correct alignment (and I have found in some cases impossible).

See the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, width=\textwidth, math upper, enhanced, 
    colframe=gray!10!white, boxrule=0pt, arc=1mm, outer arc=1mm, opacityback=0.5,
    frame hidden, borderline={0.5pt}{0pt}{gray!20!white},
    #1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Boxed equation using \texttt{empheq} and \texttt{gather*}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{gather*}
            \sigma_{xx} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{xx} + \nu(\epsilon_{yy} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{yy} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{yy} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{zz} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{zz} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{yy})\right] \\ 
            \tau_{xy} = G\gamma_{xy} \\ 
            \tau_{yz} = G\gamma_{yz} \\ 
            \tau_{xz} = G\gamma_{xz}
        \end{empheq}
        \item Boxed equation using \texttt{empheq} and \texttt{flalign*}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{flalign*}
            \sigma_{xx} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{xx} + \nu(\epsilon_{yy} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{yy} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{yy} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{zz} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{zz} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{yy})\right] \\ 
            \tau_{xy} = G\gamma_{xy} \\ 
            \tau_{yz} = G\gamma_{yz} \\ 
            \tau_{xz} = G\gamma_{xz}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output.
[image: Example alignments with box.]

Comment: the mis-alignment in your `flalign` is unrelated to the boxing, you have used an alignment environemnt with no `&` points specified so everything is on the left hand side of an equation with no right hand side so is pushed flush right, hence your comment about no centering. but also your box is using `\textwidth` when it shoukd b eusing `\linewidth` so that it fits in the indented list item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tcbox needs to be told to respect its own width key with `tcbox width=forced center` (one of the alignments gives an overfull warning here but I think it's spurious)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, width=\linewidth, math upper, enhanced, 
    colframe=gray!10!white, boxrule=0pt, arc=1mm, outer arc=1mm, opacityback=0.5,
    frame hidden, borderline={0.5pt}{0pt}{gray!20!white},tcbox width=forced center
    #1}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Boxed equation using \texttt{empheq} and \texttt{gather*}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{flalign*}
            \sigma_{xx} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{xx} + \nu(\epsilon_{yy} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{yy} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{yy} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{zz} = \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{zz} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{yy})\right] \\ 
            \tau_{xy} = G\gamma_{xy} \\ 
            \tau_{yz} = G\gamma_{yz} \\ 
            \tau_{xz} = G\gamma_{xz}
        \end{empheq}
        \item Boxed equation using \texttt{empheq} and \texttt{gather*}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{gather*}
    a=b\\
   c=d
        \end{empheq}
        \item Boxed equation using \texttt{empheq} and \texttt{flalign*}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{flalign*}
            \sigma_{xx} &= \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{xx} + \nu(\epsilon_{yy} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{yy} &= \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{yy} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{zz} &= \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{zz} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{yy})\right] \\ 
            \tau_{xy} &= G\gamma_{xy} \\ 
            \tau_{yz} &= G\gamma_{yz} \\ 
            \tau_{xz} &= G\gamma_{xz}
        \end{empheq}
        \item Boxed equation using \texttt{empheq} and \texttt{align*}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{align*}
            \sigma_{xx} &= \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{xx} + \nu(\epsilon_{yy} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{yy} &= \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{yy} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{zz})\right] \\ 
            \sigma_{zz} &= \frac{E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\left[(1-\nu)\epsilon_{zz} + \nu(\epsilon_{xx} + \epsilon_{yy})\right] \\ 
            \tau_{xy} &= G\gamma_{xy} \\ 
            \tau_{yz} &= G\gamma_{yz} \\ 
            \tau_{xz} &= G\gamma_{xz}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thanks.